# Error: could not find function "stat_sum_single" [ggplot2]

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to use "stat_sum_single" with a factor variable but I get the error:

```
Error: could not find function "stat_sum_single"
```

I tried converting the factor variable to a numeric but it doesn't seem to work - any ideas?

Full code:

```
 ggplot(sn, aes(x = person,y = X, group=Plan, colour = Plan)) +
              geom_line(size=0.5) +
              scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1.5)) +
              scale_x_discrete(breaks = c(0,50,100), labels= c(0,50,100)) +
              labs(x = "X",y = "%") +
              stat_sum_single(mean, geom = 'line', aes(x = as.numeric(as.character(person))), size = 3, colour = 'red')
```

Data:

```
Plan  person X       m  mad  mmad
1  1 95 0.323000 0.400303 0.12
1  2 275 0.341818 0.400303 0.12
1  3  2 0.618000 0.400303 0.12
1  4 75 0.320000 0.400303 0.12
1  5 13 0.399000 0.400303 0.12
1  6 20 0.400000 0.400303 0.12
2  7 219 0.393000 0.353350 0.45
2  8 50 0.060000 0.353350 0.45
2  9 213 0.390000 0.353350 0.45
2  15 204 0.496100 0.353350 0.45
2  19 19 0.393000 0.353350 0.45
2  24 201 0.388000 0.353350 0.45
3  30 219 0.567 0.1254 0.89
3  14 50 0.679 0.1254 0.89
3  55 213 0.1234 0.1254 0.89
3  18 204 0.6135 0.1254 0.89
3  59 19 0.39356 0.1254 0.89
3  101 201 0.300 0.1254 0.89
```

Person is a factor variable.

Answer (score 2):

Function `stat_sum_single()` isn't directly implemented in library `ggplot2` but this function should be defined before using as shown in the help file of function `stat_summary()`.

```
stat_sum_single <- function(fun, geom="point", ...) {
  stat_summary(fun.y=fun, colour="red", geom=geom, size = 3, ...)
}
```

Comment: I've just used that... and added `stat_sum_single(mean)` to the code but all the different lines for each group have now changed... instead of creating one mean line... unless I've misunderstood how `stat_sum_single` works

Comment: I assuming you mean to put it in the `stat_sum_single` function?

Comment: Line `stat_sum_single(mean,geom="line")` should work (without all other information you are adding). If this doesn't work then I can't help you because you haven't provided data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the ggplot2 cran package:
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/ggplot2.pdf

on page 185, there is an example of using stat_sum_single.

I believe you need to somehow define it first in stat_summary.